# Building a custom credential provider for Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, winlogon

After looking through the code for building custom credential providers for Windows 7, I managed to get my own tile to show up on the logon screen, and can logon as the desired user. However, I am trying to implement a system where an event (a Bluetooth device in range) triggers a logon/unlock, without needing to click on the tile.

I can set it to fill in the password automatically (maybe I will implement pulling the password *from* the device), but either way, I must click the tile first. If it is locked, I need to click "Other Credentials" before that, too.

How would I go about implementing the logon credential provider *without* displaying a tile on the logon screen? It would be nice if I could keep the existing password option focused, and bypass it the moment the device comes in range.

**EDIT**: I made some progress, but I still think I need to do this without a tile. If I set the `*pbAutoLogon` parameter to `true`, and fill in the username and password before that, then the following behavior occurs:

- If the default credential is selected (lock/unlock), then I need to click on "other credentials". If I log off, both credentials are displayed by default.
- If both credentials are shown, and my provider is enabled *after* that, then the logon is automatic.
- If my provider is enabled first, then "other credentials" is selected, I still need to click on my provider, after which logon is automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your credential settings to log in automatically and then your provider needs to tell LoginUI that the credentials have changed.

One of the sample credential providers supplied by microsoft works in this way.